# Need to Identify Certain Cells and then move the whole row to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

There is a master order form that has several SKU numbers on it such as 22-1,22-99, 11-1,11-22 etc. What I have been struggling to do is identify all the cells that start with the same number and then select the entire row to move them to a new worksheet. The code provided moves a single cell but I have to move the entire row next with that cell.

```vb
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim row As Long

    For row = 2 To 1000
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If Range("A" & row).Value Like "*save*" Then
            ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
            Range("I" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
            Range("A" & row).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The output needed would be all the SKUs that start with the same number get moved to a new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Range.EntireRow` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow

You can select your entire row like this:

```
ws.Range("*any cell in the row you want*").EntireRow.Select
```

then do what you want with the row (i.e, move it, copy it, etc)

Edit2: full working code which should do what you want it to do.

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim row As Long

    For row = 2 To 1000
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If Range("A" & row).Value Like "*save*" Then
            ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
            Range("A" & row).EntireRow Cut Sheet2.Range("I" & row)  'cut and paste to Sheet2
            Range("A" & row).Value = ""  'delete row for cleanup purposes
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ive been looking for a solution like this but am not sure how to implement it as im not sure how to make the specified cells the active ones. I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: I tried using "ActiveCell.Cut("I:I") But it Returns "Object Required"

Comment: "Object Required" means that you most likely didn't have an ActiveCell object selected.  Anyways, I edited my answer with a working sample.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, unfortunately my understanding of VBA is minimal. Could you define what you meant by "for loop logic, if statement logic etc. as Im struggling to figure out what to put into your code

Comment: edited again with your logic. Just copy and paste and it should work.

Comment: It wont paste as the copy and paste areas arent the same size

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Findandcut()
Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1


    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If .Cells(rw, 1).Value Like "*11-*" Then
            ' Cut the value and then blank the source and shift up
            .Cells(rw, 2).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastrow, 1)
            .Cells(rw, 2).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
        End If
    End With
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row +1
Next
End Sub
```

I think this should do what you are looking for.

Comment: IT WORKED. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok it works for one value that starts with a certain number but leaves the rest. For example if i have 11-1, 11-2, and 11-3 it will only move 11-2 to the other worksheet. Here is the code i used:

Comment: Sub Findandcut()
Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If .Cells(rw, 1).Value Like "*11-*" Then
            ' Cut the value and then blank the source and shift up
            .Cells(rw, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastrow, 1)
            '.Cells(rw, 2).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub

Comment: Matt I edited the above code this should do what you are attempting to do.